# Difference between angular as global variable and parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a factory of Angular. There was a critical error for me. I wandered to fix it. Finally, I cleared this problem... without reason. So I need clear description of below  code problem.

Here is my code A:

```
    angular
    .module('BinD', ['ngSails'])
    .factory('UserService', function ($sails) {
        ...
    });
```

And another B is:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('BinD', ['ngSails'])
    .factory('UserService', function ($sails) {
        ...
    });
})(angular);
```

And the error part is:

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('BinD', ['ngSails'])
    .controller('SignUpCtrl', function ($scope, $window, UserService) {
```

code B works well. code A made error message "UserServiceProvider is unknown(may?)". I really don't know why aforemetioned two same code works differently. Let me know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the .`factory` call in a function shouldn't make any difference.  I think you must have made a different change as-well.

In your third code snippet, when you call `.module` with two parameters you create a new module.  This would overwrite the module you created in either "Code A" or "Code B".

**You are not reusing the same module, but creating a new one.  Therefore it makes sense that your UserService does not exist on the new module.**

Your last snippet should call `.module('BinD')` with only one parameter.  Just the name of the module you want to use.

```
angular
    .module('BinD')
    .controller('SignUpCtrl', function ($scope, $window, UserService) {
```

---

Another option is that you only call `.module` once, and save it.

```
var app = angular.module('BinD', ['ngSails']);
```

Then later you can call `app.controller` or `app.factory` without having to worry about the syntax.

Comment: Aha, so I declare different module 'BinD' and module have to be managed a external variable. Is it?

Comment: Your second approach will never work in his case..As in second part he is using IIFE pattern..

Comment: @user3413534  You can manage it in an external variable if you find that easier.  That is normally what I do.

Comment: @PankajParkar, yes, obviously the `app` variable will need to be in scope where it is referenced.  So either use window.app or $window.app or return it from the IIFE.

Comment: @BuhBuh Then is there other advance way? my brain don't imagine other way.

Comment: @user3413534  The other way is to type `.module('BinD')`.  This means **get** the module.  The important part is that you only **create** the module   `.module('BinD', ['ngSails'])` once.  Do you see the difference between these two?

Comment: why do create extra `var` while `angular.module('BinD')` will have the same thing..

Comment: @BaHwanHan   No problem! It's nice you updated your profile to choose a name. Don't forget to click the green tick to choose your favourite answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your **Code A** or **Code B** in both part you had created one module `BinD` with the dependency of `ngSails` and then you are registering factory with that module, but **Code A** will declare a variable globally if you are using it & **Code B** will do the coding using IIFE pattern which will make your variable available inside the declared function only. But that doesn't related your error which you are getting.

Inside your controller you want utilize that factory, but while you are creating `controller` you shouldn't create a new module like by doing `angular.module('BinD', ['ngSails'])`, which will flush the previously registered factory(or other components) with the `BinD` module and will create a new module with name `BinD`. That's why after injecting  `UserService` inside your controller is throwing an `$injector` error, because the `UserService` is not available inside that module.

**Controller**

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('BinD') //<- utilizing already created module
    .controller('SignUpCtrl', function ($scope, $window, UserService) {
```